# Can't compile swagger library with enum

Tags: java, android, rest, swagger

I have a REST API library, generated in `swagger.io` and I want to compile it to `.jar` file. The problem is I have 2 classes, containing `enum` definition, which doesn't compile and returns a syntax error.

```
public enum FormatEnum {
   string,  float,  integer
};
```

Here are the erros.

```
...\src\main\java\io\swagger\client\model\DataDictionary.java:26: error: <identifier> expected
 string,  float,  integer
        ^
...\src\main\java\io\swagger\client\model\DataDictionary.java:26: error: ',', '}', or ';' expected
 string,  float,  integer
          ^
...\src\main\java\io\swagger\client\model\DataDictionary.java:26: error: '}' expected
 string,  float,  integer
                ^
...\src\main\java\io\swagger\client\model\DataDictionary.java:26: error: <identifier> expected
 string,  float,  integer
```

Answer (score 0):

The `float` is a data type in Java. Hence it will expect a variable declaration and hence you are getting a compilation error.

You might consider defining an `enum` like the following instead.

```
public enum FormatEnum {
    string, flt, integer
}
```